# how to reloading fragment after transaction

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using swipe view with ViewPager to display tabs in project.
I am adding three tabs(fragments) to AlertTabsPagerAdapter using

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new FragmentA();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new FragmentB();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new FragmentC();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am having two problems:

1. By default `OffscreenPageLimit` of `ViewPager` is two, so in my case for first time *FragmentA* and *FragmentB* will get created. I want to reload or recreate *FragmentB* on swipe from *FragmentA*. How can I achieve this?
2. In the first tab (i.e. *FragmentA*) I am having multiple fragments like *FragmentA* through *FragmentD*. For this I am replacing *FragmentA* with *FragmentD* using `FragmentTransaction`.
   After the fragment transaction onback key press from *FragmentD* i am getting back to *FragmentA*, but now I want to reload  or recreate *FragmentA*.

Comment: It is very puzzeling to me what you are asking. As for your first question I assume I could help you by saying that `ViewPager` has a method called `setOffscreenPageLimit(int count)`

Comment: Thank you avalancha for reply. setOffScrennPageLimit() is not working. by default two fragments get loaded. My second question is that after fragmenttransaction for example from fragmentA -> fragmentD. on back key press in fragmentD i am getting fragmentA but now i want to reload contents of fragmentA